# List View using a calculated Column Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calculated-column-formula

I have a list view I'm trying to set up using a calculated column to return yes or no by calculating dates. The user enters a date in a form, and the column should reference the created date, calculate and return a yes or no. When I create a list view filtering out yes or no I get no results, however the column correctly populates the yes/no result on the list.

```
=IF(
AND([Current Scheduled Date]>[Created]+1,[Type of Job]="TC"),"Yes"
    ,IF(AND([Current Scheduled Date]>[Created]+5,[Type of Job]="PW"),"Yes","No"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - I was able to resolve this by changing the yes/no choice result to single line of text containing "Yes" or "No" in the edit column section, and setting the filters to apply if the column contained "Yes".